# Force www for specific subfolders

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to add a Rewrite condition in order to keep www on all admin pages and on update.php

I tried to make a condition like in the following to exclude admin but without succes...

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]

 RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !^admin$

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

maybe one of you can help me sorting out this?
I'm unfortuately not so familiar with mod rewrite...

Thanks to all of you

Herve

Answer (score 2):

Try this condition instead of your second condition:

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !^/(admin($|/)|update\.php$)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'www')===false)
 header('location:'.'http://www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  ); ?>
```